# Nested model properties value null

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I have below class which contains nested model property

```
public class TestClass
    {
        public string DropdownControlHtml { get; set; }


        public TestClass1 TestClass1 { get; set; } = new();
    }
```

From controller i am returning object of testClass class like below

```
return View(testClass);
```

But when I submit form I am getting all the property of testClass as null.My button type is Button and using ajax call to post form data.

Comment: Can you share more code about Controller.cs and ajax?

Comment: In ajax i am pos form data using const formData = $("#frmCustAppSelection").serialize()

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the name of properties of `TestClass1` is right.For example:

TestClass1 :

```
 public class TestClass1 {
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
```

view:

```
<form id="frmCustAppSelection" method="post">
    <select name="DropdownControlHtml">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>

    </select>
    <input name="TestClass1[Id]" />
    <input type="button" onclick="postdata()" value="test">
</form>
<script>
        function postdata() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "GetTestClass",
                type: 'post',
                data:$("#frmCustAppSelection").serialize(),
                success: function (response) {
                }
                });
        }
</script>
```

Action:

```
public IActionResult GetTestClass(TestClass testClass)
        {
            return View(testClass);
        }
```